# how can i get the ID on firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I can't seem to get the ID. All that it returns is the cannedLst.name but I can't seem to get the ID.

```
.controller("Canned", ["$scope", "$firebaseArray","Data", function($scope, $firebaseArray, $ionicModal, Data) {
    $scope.deleteItem = function(cannedLst) {
    $scope.cannedLsts.$remove(cannedLst); 
    };

    $scope.addData = {};
    $scope.addPrice = function() {

      var price = $scope.addData.store1price;
      var editRef = new Firebase('https://pricemonitoringsys.firebaseio.com/dti/-KB7IIkAqZ07SfUOKw0l');
      editRef.update({ 
        store1price: price
      });
    };

    var cannedRef = new Firebase("https://pricemonitoringsys.firebaseio.com/dti")
    $scope.cannedGoods = $firebaseArray(cannedRef);
    var query = cannedRef.orderByChild("category").equalTo("canned");
    $scope.cannedLsts = $firebaseArray(query);
  }
])
```

Comment: It seems like you are looking for .key() The magic of firebase allows you to make updates without extracting the key in your own code, so I'm not sure where you would like it to be added. Can you give us more information on what you are trying to do with the key or where you are trying to get it?

Comment: @LukeSchlangen hi sir i am trying to get the key of a data in my firebase array so i can pass it to a controller where i can be able to edit the data within the key i can figure it out ive tried almost everything